# Deleting data with brushedpoints in shiny/ Unterstanding reactive variables

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I want to be able to delete data points by selecting them in the plot.

This exemplary code does the following:
In the Ui i create 2 selectInputs, which controls what data is used for the x and y axis. Then i create a plot and enable selecting points in the plot. Under the plot the currently selected points are shown. There is also a "DeleteData" button, but that one is not yet connected to anything.

In the server i create a dataframe "de" and assign my x and y (XVar,YVar) axis the values of the ui. Then i try to creative a reactive Value for main dataframe

```
dePlot<-reactive({de})
```

My goal with this variables is:
Sometimes i want to change the underlying data permanently (eg. deleting data) then i want to write in "de". Sometimes i want a variable which resets everytime to "de" in every eg. observer or output event. 
I have the feeling i'm not really accomplishing this goal in this way..

Then i create the plot.

Then comes the output$brush_info and observe event.
The "output$brush_info" gets the current value of dePlot and filters is for the currently used x and y axis. This way i don't delete data which is not currently displayed in the plot. And then the selected points are sent to the ui.

The observe event takes the selected values and filters every selected row out of the dataframe and then saves it to the main data frame "de". The

```
print(de)
```

shows me that the filtering is working as intended.
But this actually does not update "de" and thus also not "dePlot", so my plot remains unchanged. I guess this is because i'm "caught" in the observe event and can't pass on variables from there. I have the feeling, i'm really close, but simply don't understand reactive values enough to finish it.

I hope i made the problem not too confusing and every help is appreciated.

My ui

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyFiles")
library("shinydashboard")
library("shinyBS")
library("plotly")
library("jpeg")
library("imager")

shinyUI(

    dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(disable = T),
      dashboardSidebar(width = 200,

                       sidebarMenu(width=3,
                                   menuItem(startExpanded = T,

                                     selectInput("XVar","Please Select X-Axis",
                                                 choices=c("eins","zwei","drei"),selected="eins"),
                                     selectInput("YVar","Please Select Y-Axis",
                                                 choices=c("eins","zwei","drei"),selected="zwei")
                                           )
                                   )
                       ),
      dashboardBody(width=9,


              tabItem(tabName = 'box2',
                      tabBox(width = 16,
                             tabPanel("Long time data",plotOutput("myPlot", click = "plot1_click",brush = brushOpts(id = "plot1_brush"))
                                     ,actionButton('DeleteData?','DeleteSelectedData'),column(width = 6,h4("Brushed points"),verbatimTextOutput("brush_info"))
                                     )
                             )
                      )        
              )
      )
)
```

My server

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session){

eins<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
zwei<-c(4,6,3,4,400,-500,900,8,12,5)
drei<-c(989,663,74,543,222,1541,1515,12,525,21)
isolate({de<-data.frame(eins,zwei,drei)})

XVar<-reactive({input$XVar})
YVar<-reactive({input$YVar})

dePlot<-reactive({de})

output$myPlot <-renderPlot({

  ggplot(data=dePlot())+
    geom_line(aes_string(x=XVar(),y=YVar()
                         )
              )
  })

output$brush_info <- renderPrint({

  deBrush<-dePlot()[,c(XVar(),YVar())]
  brushedPoints(deBrush, input$plot1_brush)
  })

observe({

  Var1<-brushedPoints(dePlot(), input$plot1_brush,allRows = TRUE)

  Var12<-as.numeric((row.names(Var1[Var1$selected_==TRUE,])))

  de<-dePlot()[-Var12,]

  print(de)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
```

Almost only styling changes in `ui`:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 200,
    sidebarMenu(
      width = 3, 
      menuItem(
        startExpanded = TRUE,
        selectInput("XVar", "Please Select X-Axis", 
                    choices = c("eins", "zwei", "drei"), selected = "eins"), 
        selectInput("YVar","Please Select Y-Axis",
                    choices = c("eins", "zwei", "drei"), selected = "zwei")
      )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    width=9,
    tabItem(
      tabName = 'box2',
      tabBox(
        width = 16,
        tabPanel(
          "Long time data", 
          plotOutput("myPlot", click = "plot1_click", 
                     brush = brushOpts(id = "plot1_brush")), 
          actionButton('DeleteSelectedData', 'DeleteData ? '), 
          actionButton('ResetData', 'Reset data'), 
          column(
            width = 6,
            h4("Brushed points"), 
            verbatimTextOutput("brush_info"))
        )
      )
    )        
  )
)
```

- `input$...`s don't need to be wrapped in `reactive({ })`
- we need some "state" (though that's usually best avoided in Shiny), and can use `reactiveVal()` for that
- the effect of `actionButton`s is more easily controlled with `observeEvent()` than `observe()`

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  eins <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
  zwei <- c(4, 6, 3, 4, 400, -500, 900, 8, 12, 5)
  drei <- c(989, 663, 74, 543, 222, 1541, 1515, 12, 525, 21)
  de <- data.frame(eins, zwei, drei)

  rx_de <- reactiveVal(de)

  output$myPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = rx_de()) +
      geom_line(aes_string(x = input$XVar, y = input$YVar))
  })

  output$brush_info <- renderPrint({
    brushedPoints(rx_de(), input$plot1_brush)[, c(input$XVar, input$YVar)]
  })

  observeEvent(input$DeleteSelectedData, {
    Var1 <- brushedPoints(rx_de(), input$plot1_brush, allRows = TRUE)
    rx_de(Var1[!Var1$selected_, names(Var1) != "selected_", drop = FALSE])
  })

  observeEvent(input$ResetData, {
    rx_de(de)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```